# Vuelidate with data nesting and validation groups

Tags: validation, vue.js, vue-component, vuelidate

Im using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) in my project. I have a form made with [Vue Form Wizard](http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-form-wizard/#/) and with [Vuelidate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/) to validate the fields. At certain point of the form, the user will be able to add multiples addresses, so I created a array named 'addresses' into the *data* of my *component*.

```
addresses: [
    { 
        street: ''
        //there will be more itens here in the future
    }
]
```

Now, in order to validate the fields, I created a [validation group](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-validation-groups) where Im gonna add this field, but the point is, I dont know how to 'link' the field (that is inside my array) into the validation group.

In Vuelidate Documentation, there is a section [Data Nesting](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-data-nesting), but i didn't find how to use it with validation groups.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3unmfk5s/25/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but if I understand it correctly then I guess you can just create a custom validator on the `addresses` array, and in the validator validate single address objects.

```
validations: {
 addresses: {
    customValidator: customValidatorFunction
 }
},
```

Then the customValidatorFunction is gonna get the whole array of addresses, and you can use it to validate all/any object you want in your custom way.